Transform a set of nonlinear equations in state space form
I have to solve a multi-body dynamic problem numerically in Matlab. The set of equations has been computed in Mathematica. To solve it in Matlab i have to transform it into state space representation. I did a similar problem a few years ago (same problem but without the s(t), s'(t) and s''(t) and onbut can't remember how
it worked in Mathematica.
The sets of the three equations is:
DGL = {m (2 (4 h^2 + 3 r^2) Cos[θ[t]] Sin[2 ϕ[t]] Derivative[1][θ][t]^2
        + 48 (r - r Cos[θ[t]] + s[t] + h Sin[θ[t]]) Derivative[1][s][t] Derivative[1][ϕ][t] + 
      2 (-24 h r Cos[2 θ[t]] + 
         24 h Cos[θ[t]] (r + s[t]) + 
         24 r (r + s[t]) Sin[θ[t]] + (16 h^2 - 9 r^2) Sin[2 θ[t]]) Derivative[1][θ][t] Derivative[1][ϕ][t] + 
      12 Sin[ϕ[t]] (r^2 Derivative[1][ϕ][t]^2 + 
         2 (r (-1 + Cos[θ[t]]) - s[t] - h Sin[θ[t]]) u''[t]) + 
      24 Cos[ϕ[t]] (r - r Cos[θ[t]] + s[t] + 
         h Sin[θ[t]]) v''[t] + 
      2 Sin[2 ϕ[t]] (-3 r^2 Derivative[1][ϕ][t]^2 + (4 h^2 + 3 r^2) Sin[θ[t]] θ''[t]) + (16 h^2 + 57 r^2 - 
         16 h^2 Cos[2 θ[t]] + 
         3 r^2 (-16 Cos[θ[t]] + 3 Cos[2 θ[t]] - 
            8 Cos[ϕ[t]] + 2 Cos[2 ϕ[t]]) + 
         24 (-2 r Cos[θ[t]] s[t] + s[t] (2 r + s[t]) + 
            2 h (r + s[t]) Sin[θ[t]] - 
            h r Sin[2 θ[t]])) ϕ''[t]) == 
   0, m (24 g r Cos[θ[t]] - 
      24 g h Sin[θ[
         t]] + (24 h r (-Cos[θ[t]] + Cos[2 θ[t]]) + 
         4 (-6 r^2 + (4 h^2 + 3 r^2) Cos[2 ϕ[t]]) Sin[θ[
            t]] - 24 s[
           t] (h Cos[θ[t]] + r Sin[θ[t]]) + (-16 h^2 + 
            9 r^2) Sin[2 θ[t]]) Derivative[1][ϕ][t]^2 + 
      24 (h Cos[θ[t]] + r Sin[θ[t]]) s''[t] + 
      24 Cos[ϕ[t]] (h Cos[θ[t]] + r Sin[θ[t]]) u''[t] + 
      24 (h Cos[θ[t]] + r Sin[θ[t]]) Sin[ϕ[t]] v''[t] + 
      24 r Cos[θ[t]] w''[t] - 
      24 h Sin[θ[t]] w''[t] + 
      32 h^2 θ''[t] + 
      30 r^2 θ''[t] + 
      2 (4 h^2 + 3 r^2) Sin[θ[t]] Sin[
        2 ϕ[t]] ϕ''[t]) == 0, 
  m ((r Cos[θ[t]] - h Sin[θ[t]]) Derivative[
        1][θ][
        t]^2 + (r (-1 + Cos[θ[t]]) - s[t] - 
         h Sin[θ[t]]) Derivative[1][ϕ][t]^2 + s''[t] + 
      Cos[ϕ[t]] u''[t] + 
      Sin[ϕ[t]] v''[
        t] + (h Cos[θ[t]] + 
         r Sin[θ[t]]) θ''[t]) == 0}


Now how do I transform it into the statespace representation for the variables Theta(t), Phi(t) and s(t)? u(t), v(t) and w(t) are external excitation functions due to earthquake ground motion.  I'm sorry I use Mathematica not very often so I really need your help! I read the other articles with topics for statespace but it didn't help...
Thanks in advance!

Please type out all Mathematica code, in proper mathematica syntax, properly formatted in code blocks, instead of posting images. Images cannot be read by screen readers, and having the code typed out allows us to copy and paste the code directly into our own copies of Mathematica. Please edit your post by clicking the grey edit button below your post, and including the code. See here if you're having trouble with the copying and pasting.

I tried but not sure if this is satisfying...

Are you looking for this?

Why solve it in Matlab rather than Mathematica?

@march: yes this is what I'm looking for. I already tried this but I guess I'm too stupid to enter everything correctly to get the desired output. Can someone help me?

Unfortunately, I know next to nothing about what a state space representation is, so I can't help in this case.
